# Displaying external site in plain text

Tags: javascript, api

I'd like to add the functionality for my app, where each selected url generates the next page in plain text. For example, when a new story is clicked now, it takes the user straight to the external source (e.g. cnn). How would I go about writing my code so that the external source generates in plain text, only?

Comment: What you are asking is far from trivial, would require server side scraping and a knowledge of the page structure of specific sites

Comment: Look at BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: This is actually not an easy task. There's an api service called diffbot that uses artificial intelligence to do it. https://www.diffbot.com/